# Do I distort information stored in covariance matrix if I normalize the matrix to range of $[-1 , 1]$

Tags: matlab, optimization, covariance, covariance-matrix, mutual-information

I am using covariance matrix to maximize mutual information between samples that I selected and sample that I did not selected. The optimization algorithm that I use is [sfo_greedy_lazy](https://las.inf.ethz.ch/sfo/).

It computes $\log(\det(L_{S})) + \log(\det(L_{V/S}))$ where $S$ and $V/S$ selected and not selected samples respectively.The algorithm is calculating inverse of covariance matrix.But matrix is too large in dimension, (i.e $4196 \times 4196$) and also there is too small values which is less than  eps of my machine so Matlab gives error.

I tried to add small amounts to diagonal in covariance matrix but it does not always solve problem.(This method has solved the problem in a small sized matrix).

What I want to ask you, if I normalize the matrix into $[-1, 1]$ range,do I distort the information  $\log(\det(L_{S}))+\log(\det(L_{V/S}))$ ?

Comment: A principled way to do that would be to just work with $\Omega$ the correlation matrix $\Sigma=\tau\Omega\tau$, where $\tau$ is the vector of standard deviations and $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix.